# Apache Crash Dialog

Tags: apache, webserver, xampp

I'm running XAMPP on my windows machine and experiencing a problem with Apache crashing a couple times a day. When it does, a dialog pops up and I have to manually tell windows to end the program. After I do that, XAMPP automatically starts it back up in a couple of seconds with no issues. When it crashes while I'm not home though, the server is down until I get back. So I have two questions:

1. Are periodic crashes something that should be expected, or is this indicative of another issue I should be trying to pinpoint?
2. If this is something I should just learn to deal with, is there a way to automatically restart httpd.exe when these issues occur, so I don't experience down time when I'm away from home?

Comment: Could you post log messages before server restart? The Apache error log, access log and the PHP error log are high valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You'd look into log files, especially the Apache access and error logs, to see what happened, when you are not at home. I've met some similar situation: I have a problematic PHP script hosted on my server, when someone visits the page, it leads to an Apache crash.

I'd suggest you do the investigation as follows:

1. Search the timestamp of recent Apache restart.
2. Check the Apache access log to see whether there are some scripts have been accessed.
3. Manually access these scripts in your browser (to see if Apache will crash again)
4. You'd better check the PHP error log as well.

If there is really nothing suspicious, you can try **WAMP** bundle alternatively, which is also a very popular PHP development environment and **it is stable**.

Comment: The crashes seem to happen often after one of two log events. Either a search spider tries to access robots.txt and fails, or a hacker or bot pokes around for admin scripts. I have to assume that in both situations, a scan is being done on my site that's somehow triggering a script that crashes my server. I can't recreate the problem though so I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: @nathan `robots.txt` should be safe. Do the admin scripts actually exist? If yes, then you'd remove these suspicious admin scripts and wait for couple of hours to see, if server still crashes regularly. Edit `php.ini` and enable all error messages. Manually navigate these admin scripts with the same parameters in your browser to see what can happen. You are very close the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Although there aren't many cases in which one should "expect" periodic crashes, in this case you are better of reconsidering your setup. From the frontpage of the XAMPP site:

> XAMPP is the most popular PHP development environment

Sure, you can use it as "production" server, but XAMPP isn't build for hosting websites, it is intended as development server, so you don't have to manually setup Apache, PHP and MySQL on you dev machine. If you actually want to run your website for the public, setup Apache/IIS, MySQL and PHP manually, those products on there own are made for running in production. Or you can consider getting some cheap shared hosting somewhere, so you don't need to setup anything.

Comment: If you would like an easy out-of-the-box solution with Apache try BitNami WAMP stack. If it doesn't need to be Apache and you just want something easy to use that works, try Microsoft WebMatrix. If you want more power, try cygwin.

Comment: I was aware it wasn't ideal; I'm kind of stuck in this situation for the time being, since my site uses up too many CPU resources to go with shared hosting, and the traffic doesn't justify a paid dedicated host yet. I'll look into WAMP, thanks!